# Call to 'fmax' is ambiguous when cross-compiling for android

Tags: android, c++, cross-compiling

Getting `call to 'fmax' is ambiguous` when cross-compiling for android. There are three candidates:

```
src/interest-control.cpp:218:15: error: call to 'fmax' is ambiguous
     i <= fmax(limit_, pipeline_);
          ^~~~
<...>/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:196:8: note: candidate function
double  fmax(double, double) __attribute_const__;
        ^
<...>/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/math.h:1116:46: note: candidate function
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY float       fmax(float __lcpp_x, float __lcpp_y) _NOEXCEPT             {return fmaxf(__lcpp_x, __lcpp_y);}
                                             ^
<...>/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/math.h:1117:46: note: candidate function
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long double fmax(long double __lcpp_x, long double __lcpp_y) _NOEXCEPT {return fmaxl(__lcpp_x, __lcpp_y);}
```

It does make sense to me that the compiler is confused. Here are my CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS:

```
$ echo $CFLAGS 
-isystem <...>/toolchain/include/c++/4.9.x/ --sysroot=<...>/toolchain/sysroot -I<...>/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include -I<...>/toolchain/include
$ echo $CPPFLAGS
-isystem <...>/toolchain/include/c++/4.9.x/ --sysroot=<...>/toolchain/sysroot -I<...>/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include -I<...>/toolchain/include
```

The compiler, however has more system search paths:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 ./include
 ./src
 <...>/toolchain/include
 <...>/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x
 <...>/toolchain/sysroot/usr/local/include
 <...>/toolchain/lib64/clang/5.0.300080/include
 <...>/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include
```

Which leads to confusion at build time. 
When I use `-nostdinc` flag it leads to more problems (like not finding `float.h` file, etc).
I generated [standalone android toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) and use GNU Autotools for compiling the library.

My questions are:

1. Why generated toolchain is ambiguous and conflicts with it's own `sysroot` and `include/c++/4.9.x` paths?
2. Which search path directory one shall use - `sysroot` or `include/c++/4.9.x` (right now, both are used because either one is not sufficient, e.g. leads to files not found errors; but both of them result in ambiguous calls)?

Comment: Show the code that produced that error message. Chances are that the compiler is right.

Comment: @PeteBecker well, it's just a call to fmax... `i <= fmax(limit_, pipeline_);` includes `<algorithm>`

Comment: What type are i,  limit_, and pipline_?

Comment: Well, duh. **Show the code**. You need to produce the smallest **code example** you can come up with that compiles and shows the problem.

Comment: here it is: 
`int i;
 unsigned int a;
 boost::atomic<int> b;
 i = fmax(a,b);`
. and `#include <algorithm>;` and `#include <boost/atomic.hpp>;`

Comment: @TonyJ good hunch! i fixed it by explicit casting like `i <= (int)fmax((double)limit_, (double)pipeline_);`

Comment: @peetonn, fmax is for floating points, for int you can just use std::max. Also comparing unsigned int and int will give you problems. More over casting them to double than back to int could lose precision. You should really rethink what you are trying to do there. Edit: One more thing don't use c-style cast